# Xcode UIButton to UITableView not connecting

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I am designing a project where I want it to go to a table view when a button is clicked.

Here is a pic of the storyboard:[Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBnD4.png)

Here is the code for the view with the button:

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class MealViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var priceLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var caloriesLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var descriptionLabel: UILabel!


    @IBAction func addToCart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }
```

and here is the table view code:

```
import UIKit

class CartTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations
        // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false

        // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
        // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 0
    }
```

When I run it how it is, it opens a blank table. When I change the numberOfRowsInSection, it gives a sigabrt error. How can I get it to just open the view regularly?

Answer (score 0):

The function numberOfRowsInSection define the count of rows in the given section. If you define 0 the table must be empty. If you define something else the table view asks for a concrete cell for each row by calling:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

Depending on your code thats the first place to look for the crash reason. Your code snipped doesn't show it.